# Proving that homotopic maps have the same degree

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology

Let $M, N$ be compact, connected, oriented manifolds. The degree of a map $f:M \rightarrow N$ is defined as the integer $k$ which satisfies $\int_{M} f^{*}\omega  = k\int_{N}\omega$. Using the fact that homotopic maps, say $f, g$ induce the same map on the De Rham cohomology, we have $\int_{M} f^{*}\omega - \int_{M} g^{*}\omega = \int_{} d\nu$ for $\nu$ some $n-1$ form. Now if the manifold has empty boundary, we can use Stokes's theorem to conclude that this equals 0.

However, what about when the manifold does not have empty boundary? A proof that I found relies on the fact that if you have a homotopy $H(x,t)$ then $t \mapsto H_{t}^{*}\omega$ is continuous, and then using the continuity of the integral, concluding that (since the degree is always an integer), $k(t)=\frac{\int_{M}H_{t}^{*}\omega}{\int_{N}\omega}$is also continuous, hence constant. 
    Is there any other way of proving this?

Comment: Slow down. Degree is ordinarily defined for maps between compact, oriented manifolds *without boundary* (of the same dimension). With boundary, you need more hypotheses to get something homotopy invariant.  (Consider maps from a closed interval to itself.)

Comment: @TedShifrin Initially I thought that might be the case, however after checking a few different textbooks, they do not specify that this holds only for manifolds without boundary. In JM Lee's Introduction to Smooth Manifolds we also have a corollary (17.8) that homotopic maps have the same induced cohomology maps, whether or not the manifolds have boundary. So, I'm thinking the above holds, but not quite sure. I do see the problem with the interval though, namely that the degree 1 identity map is homotopic to a constant map...

Comment: Yes, absolutely, homotopic maps induce the same map on cohomology. But for degree you need to look at relative cohomology or restrict to proper maps or ... something.

Comment: What you are missing is that without an appropriate hypothesis, the ratio $\int_M f^* \omega \,\, / \,\, \int_N \omega$ need not be an integer. Therefore, while this ratio does vary continuously under a homotopy of $f$, it need not be constant.

Comment: The "theorem" you are asking about is simply false for manifolds with boundary. However, it remains true if the map $f$ and its homotopy sends boundary to boundary. This allows one to get the equality of the induced maps $H_n(M, \partial M)\to H_n(N, \partial N)$, where $n$ is the dimension of your manifolds.